# Java Symbol not found?

Tags: java

I am doing a project for my java class and I cant understand why I am getting this error. Here is my code:

```
public class address 
{ 
String Street;
String City;
String State;
String Zip;

public address()
{
Street = "";
City = "";
State = "";
Zip = "";
}

public void setStreet(String street)
{
Street = street;
}

public void setCity(String city)
{
City = city;
}

public void setState(String state)
{
State = state;
}

public void setZip(String zip)
{
Zip = zip;
}

public String getStreet()
{
retrun Street;
}

public String getCity()
{
return City;
}

public String getState()
{
return State;
}

public String getZip()
{
return Zip;
}


}
```

This is my address class for each employee. We just learned about OOP. This is the CMD output with the error:

[image]

Comment: Please learn the Java naming conventions and stick to them. Classes start with an upper-case letter. Variables and methods start with a lower-case letter. And please copy and paste the error message in your question rather than linking to an image.

Comment: Really? We're going to do spell checking on SO now?

Answer (score 2):

Typo:

```
public String getStreet()  {
    retrun Street; // should be return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`retrun` is​​​​​​​​​ misspelled.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling error. You wrote 'retrun' instead of 'return' in getStreet method.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using your IDE to generate this sort of code.  Typing it yourself just leads to typos.

```
// type two lines
public class Address {
    private String street, city, state, zip;

    // and use the IDE to generate a constructor
    public Address(String street, String city, String state, String zip) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    // generate getters and setters
    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mispelled `return`

```
public String getStreet()  {
    retrun Street; // wrong
}
```

it must be

```
public String getStreet()  {
    return Street; // correct
}
```